# Internal storage space on a Motorola android phone

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I only have 6 games downloaded and moved to my SD card but my internal storage is running how can I find out why that is? And how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Assuming you've meant internal storage is running *low* (just "running" wouldn't pose a problem), I've added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. Please start with [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which has first-aid and useful links. Also see if you can [edit] your question and add a few more details on your device: which Motorola phone is it? Can you also add a screenshot of the *Settings › Storage* screen?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what's the size of your device's internal storage, and what are these games you've downloaded? Because if you have 4GB of storage and downloaded something like [Dead Trigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.madfingergames.deadtrigger) it would be obvious that you would run out of storage space.

If it's still unclear why you ran out of storage, I would recommend two steps for you:

1. Download file manager from play store (I personally use [FX Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx)) and search for large files you've in downloads folder (or any other folders you could possibly junk).
2. Download  [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) and let it optimize storage for you.

That should help in most cases, if not, let me know ;)